# How to: mock axios when passed a config w/ typescript

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs, axios

I can't mock axios when it is uses the config convention  `axios(passAConfigObj)`. I have no problem mocking when it is `axios.get` or `axios.post`. Not trying to introduce a library, because I feel like this can be done.

I have tried mocking the request method that is going to be used `axios.post`. I tried mocking axios and giving it a return value but wants an `AxiosPromise<any>`.

`const mockedAxios = mocked(axios)`

`mockedAxios.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(2))`

`error: TS2322: Type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to type AxiosPromise<any>`

```
// auth.spec.ts
import { getAuthToken } from '../auth'

import axios from 'axios'
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils'

jest.mock('axios')

describe('getAuthToken', () => {
  const mockedAxiosPost = mocked(axios)

  it('should return ', () => {
    mockedAxiosPost.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({ data: 'response.data' })
    )

    const authToken = getAuthToken()

    expect(authToken).toEqual()
    expect(mockedAxiosPost).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(mockedAxiosPost).toHaveBeenCalledWith()

  })
})
```

```js
// auth.ts
import axios from 'axios'

export const getAuthToken = () => {

  const options = {
    url: `url`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: ''
      'Content-Type': '',
    },
    data: {},
  }

  return axios(options)
    .then(response => {
      return response
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
    })
}
```

I expect axios that gets passed a config to internally call `axios.post` thus working/passing my test.

I have other implementations of axios.post and axios.get that works with this testing style, so that is not the problem. Obviously I can just change my code to use `axios.post`, but at this point, I am curious more than anything. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This has been here for a year, and I stumbled onto this thread while trying to solve the same problem.

I was scratching my head for a while, but eventually I managed to crack it.

A bit of context to better understand how I solved it:

I mocked `axios` for usage with `jest`, and in a project using `Typescript`.

That said, this is what I ended up doing:

**__mocks__/axios.ts:**

```
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const axiosResponse: AxiosResponse = {
  data: { falseProp: 'value' },
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  config: {},
  headers: {},
};

export default {
  create: jest.fn((config) => {
     const wrapFunction = (param: any) => {
      return Promise.resolve(axiosResponse)
     }

     return wrapFunction
  })
};
```

This an example of the way I was using `axios` in the code I was trying to test:

**src/MyRequestClass.ts:**

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosError } from 'axios'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://fake-api-url',
  headers: {
      common: {
          Authorization: authToken
      }
  }
})

const request = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://fake-api-url/endpoint',
  params: {},
  data: {},
  headers: {}
}

const response = await axiosInstance(request)
```

Essentially, what I did was make it so the `create` method returns a `function` that receives the `config` object you mentioned (in my case the `request` object) and always resolves the `Promise`.

Of course, you can also make it so the `Promise` fails depending on your test cases.

Hope this helps anyone else!